# Returning a JSON array of translated content using i18n

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

**Context:** I am making a multi-language page using the `react-i18next` module of ReactJS.

**Issue:** I cannot access the arrayed JSON content.

The translated content being stored in separate JSON files for each language, **non-array content works fine and gets correctly displayed and translated**, however, I can't seem to use the arrayed content on my React components, let alone access its content through `console.log()`.

Below is an example of my `translationEN.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "Test",
  "occupations":["occupation1",
  "Part-time occupation2",
  "Language enthusiast"]
}
```

I am being able to refer to the non-array `name` using `i18n.t("name")`.
However, attempting to access my arrayed `occupations` using `i18n.t("occupations")` results in the following console.log:

`key 'occupations (en)' returned an object instead of string.`

Using `JSON.stringify()` doesn't solve the issue, neither does `console.log(i18n.t("occupations"), { returnObjects: true })` as suggested on [i18next's documentation](https://www.i18next.com/translation-function/objects-and-arrays)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem solved.
The array values can be accessed as such: `i18n.t("occupations.0")` for `occupation 1`, `i18n.t("occupations.1")` for `Part-time occupation 2` and `i18n.t("occupations.2")` for `Language enthusiast`.
I just need to loop it out to make it look cleaner.